# $Watch in Angular is not working when we try to distinguish between strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I have an AngularJs app and i created watch on a service.

I have a watch on tabs and every click i am checking if it is the second tab was selected. If it is the second tab i am doing some logic.

```
 $scope.$watch('service.currentTab.getIndex() === 1', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            if (newValue === true) {
               DO SOME LOGIC
            }
        }
    });
```

And it is working fine.

However, in my opinion it's not elegant. If someone in the future will add a tab in the second place instead of this tab my logic will ruin.

In order to fix it i added enums.js file:

```
var TabEnum = {
PAPERS: "PAPERS",
TELEPHONE: "TELEPHONE",
CELLPHONE: "CELLPHONE",
};
```

And my watch was changed to :

```
$scope.$watch('service.getCurrentTabName() === TabEnum.TELEPHONE', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            DO SOME LOGIC
        }
    });
```

Service.js:

```
app.service('service', [
function () {
this.getCurrentTabName = function(){
        var currentTab = this.currentTab;
        var currentTabName = currentTab.getTabName();
        return currentTabName;
    };
     }
 ]);
```

Why the phrase

```
$scope.$watch('service.getCurrentTabName() === TabEnum.TELEPHONE'
```

not working?

Comment: Show us the rest of the relevant code too: getTabName() and the relevant html.

Comment: And I think your solution is overly complicated. Imo it could be solved much easier if you just set some flag that keeps info on which tab is open. Or maybe just call the logic everytime your telephone tab gets clicked.

Comment: I chose do like you said! Thanks!